# RDLC reports issue

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, rdlc, rdl

I am getting a compilation error when I work with rdlc reports, here is the error:

> The report definition has an invalid target namespace
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition'
>   which cannot be upgraded.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 with SQL Server 2008.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

VS 2008 only supports ReportViewer 2008, which only supports up to RDL 2005 Schema. The namespaces being declared in the reports you listed are using RDL 2008 and RDL 2010. Those are only compatibile with ReportViewer 2010 and above, and only VS 2010 has designer support for ReportViewer 2010, and RDL 2008+ schema.

Try to change the namespace to this which is for SQL Reporting Services 2008.

```
<Report xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition">
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I already have the namespace as you mentioned in the answer and the reports were working just fine before I repaired my VS 2010 for some reason...